# How to download a module from Github

Tags: python, python-import

I am new to python and I am having trouble downloading a module from GitHub: https://github.com/petercerno/good-morning

I have looked online for solutions, but each solution I try does not work.  I have tried:

```
pip install https://github.com/petercerno/good-morning.git
```

I get an error that says, "Cannot unpack file" & "Cannot determine archive format."  I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Comment: the answer depends on what you're going to do with the downloaded code. Are you going to import this code, or run static analysis, or get some git metadata?

Comment: pip will not install from this repo because it is not a proper module (i.e. it doesn't have `setup.py` and other stuffs)

Comment: If you tried `pip install`, can we assume you want to USE the module in your python installation?

Comment: clone the repo and add it to your python path

Comment: so, if it had the setup.py it would of worked with the code I tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save [good_download.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petercerno/good-morning/master/good_download.py) and [good_morning.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petercerno/good-morning/master/good_morning.py) to the same directory as your Python script, and then import them:

```
import good_morning
import good_download
# do stuff!
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked!!! I appreciate the help